# Error using ransac.predict(line_X.reshape(1,-1))

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I wrote this code - using housing data from kaggle:

```
X = df['RM'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df['MEDV'].values
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor
ransac = RANSACRegressor() 
ransac.fit(X,y)
inlier_mask = ransac.inlier_mask_
outlier_mask = np.logical_not(inlier_mask)
np.arange(3,10,1)
line_X = np.arange(3,10,1)
line_y_ransac = ransac.predict(line_X.reshape(1,-1))
```

I got this error on `line_y`:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 7)
```

Comment: Can you edit your error msg. Add a newline before ValueError. Also, can. you please explain what you are trying to do and what research you have done to fix this? Stack Overflow guidelines requires you to have done some research before you present the question. This question does not reflect adequate research

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I should've passed `-1, 1` instead of `1, -1` to `line_X.reshape`:

```
line_X.reshape(-1,1))
```